# Storing days off for user

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, backend

I'm looking for good solution for storing days off for users.

My app need to log when users will be available, so in User Model I want to create attribute where I will find all pick dates for days off (day off - mean user will be not available).

I started from creating model for DayOff:

```py
class DayOff(models.Model):
     date = models.DateField()
```

and add it to User model:

```py
class User(BaseUser):
....
    days_off = models.ManyToMany(DayOff)
```

Maybe there is better solution?

Cheers
Fenrir

Comment: How many users do you have? approximately. and How you are going to **fill** your `days_off` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off looking into [rrule](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) or [django-scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler) since generally, people are going to want to book off weeks at a time etc and you don't want to have to try and manage that by singular days off.

But I'd be tempted (and have done) to just look into Google Calendar's API / Python SDK and let them handle the heavy lifting of trying to manage this data.

Comment: Thanks for Your help !